# Converting a decimal to price format in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey I am using the ruby on rails framework and I have a price variable that is a decimal. Naturally values like $39.99 is fine but when the price is $39.90 my app shows the price as $39.9 How could I change that.

**My view**

> %b price
>
> = @product.price

Answer (score 9, accepted):

rails includes the `number_to_currency(@product.price)` helper.  Little simpler and easier to remember.

Answer (score 5):

The standard answer here is to use [sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

```
sprintf("$%2.2f", @product.price)
```

This will format your number with a leading dollar sign, then the number to two decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can write your custom helper method for this.

```
def num_to_currency price
  "$#{price.to_i}."+"#{(price % 1.0)}"[2..3]
end

1.9.3 (main):0 > num_to_currency 6.90
=> "$6.90"
```